# How to disable lock screen on Android

Tags: android

I want to disable the lock screen in a certain app. My problem is that this also disables the lock screen for the whole phone. So I added `lock.reenableKeyguard();` to the `onPause()` method, but this is called not only when the user exits the app but everytime a new activity starts in that app. Do I have to disable the lock screen in every activity and add this `onPause` method? Is there way to manage this only in the first activity that is shows when the app starts?

Btw I also reenable the lock screen in the `onStop` and `onDestroy` methods. The other problem with `onPause` is that it is also called when I turn off the phone's screen (by pressing the power button or what is that called), so when I first open the app, I turn off the screen then turn it on, there is no lock screen, but when I turn it off-on again, there is it, as I reenable it in the `onPause` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with this a couple of hours I figured out I forget to implement onResume():

```
 public void onResume()    {
            lock.disableKeyguard();
            super.onResume();
        }
```

This way every time I open the activity/turn on the screen, the lock screen is disabled.